# Медианный фильтр двумерного массива C#

Tags: c#, фильтрация, алгоритм, фильтры

Имеется массив координат точек (Х, У) объекта, медианной фильтрацией нужно отфильтровать данные значения, чтобы они были без перепадов. Все примеры, которые я нашел, направлены на фильтрацию изображений или представлены для одномерного массива, в моем же случае нужно сделать что-то вроде уравнивания значений некой функции.

Comment: А чем, по-вашему, отличается обработка изображения и двумерного масива произвольных значений? Изображение и есть двумерный массив значений. Насчёт алгоритма - первая ссылка, выданная Гуглом по запросу "медианный фильтр" ведёт на статью в Википедии, в которой представлен псевдокод алгоритма медианной фильтрации для одного канала изображения. Как раз ваш случай.

Comment: На вики был, псевдокод видел, но из-за путаницы с window height/width, image height/width не могу интерпритировать его на нужный мне. Не могли бы вы перевести так сказать? Спасибо.

Comment: Вы же пишете, что нашли алгоритмы медианной фильтрации изображений. Что вас в них смутило? То что в них используются три цветовых канала (RGB)? Так это поправимо - просто уберите два лишних канала, и у вас останется именно тот алгоритм, который вам нужен.

Comment: Если вдруг самому лень разбираться можно чуть больше погуглить и найти что-то типа этого:
http://www.miszalok.de/Samples/IP/median_filter/median_filter.pdf

Comment: Ну, в общем, дело в том, что у пикселя помимо координаты Х У существует ещё и параметр цвета, именно он сравнивается в медианном фильтре, а так как у меня этой велечины нет, то было решено взять сумму растояний от данной точки к соседним, тем самым получить сравнимую величину.

Comment: @Bobchik: Не вполне ясно, что вы называете медианным фильтром для вашего случая. В классическом случае это преобразование значения функции от координат. Что нужно преобразовывать в вашем случае? Y как функцию от X? И потом, вы должны ещё задать краевые условия.

Comment: ну так Вам и предлагают выше убрать два канала цвета

Comment: @gost: так цвета-то у ТС вообще нету, только координаты.

Comment: @VladD: согласен. но почему если мы хотим убрать перепады по Y нельзя взять значение в точке X,Y за Y

Comment: @gost: Это может сработать, если данные устроены как функция Y от X. Но если точки расположены, например, по окружности, такое не прокатит. ТС должен лучше нас знать, какой смысл его данных, и что есть функция чего.

Comment: @VladD: точно так! Тут и говорят: Мало данных.